# Show $E[ (Y - E(Y|X)) (E(Y|X) - h(X))] = 0$

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation

Show that $E[ (Y - E(Y|X)) (E(Y|X) - h(X))] = 0,$ where $X, Y$ are random variables with constant means and $h(x)$ is an arbitrary function.

So far, I have expanded out the expectation and used linearity to get:

$$E[YE(Y|X)] - E[Yh(X)] - E\left[E(Y|X)^2\right]+E[h(X)E(Y|X)].$$

I do not really know how to proceed. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: An idea to try:  $E[Y\mid X]$ is a random variable that is a function of $X$ (not $Y$ !!), say $g(X)$, with the property that $E[g(X)] = E[E[Y\mid X]] = E[Y]$.

Answer (score 3):

The first $E$ can be explained in two ways:

Let $h(X) = 0$ and $E(Y|X) = g(X)$. $E(Y) = c$, it can be get by getting marginal distribution of $Y$. Then 
$$E_Y[ (Y - E(Y|X)) (E(Y|X) - h(X))] = [c - g(X)][g(X)-h(X)]$$
The condition for it to be zero is $g(X) = c$ or $g(X)=h(X)$. For example, $Y$ and $X$ are independent.

Another way:
$$E_XE_{Y|X}[ (Y - E(Y|X)) (E(Y|X) - h(X))] = E_X[ (E(Y|X) - E(Y|X)) (E(Y|X) - h(X))] = 0$$